# How to type logical expressions in WolframAlpha?

Tags: logic, wolfram-alpha

Usually WolframAlpha understands what logical expression I have entered but sometimes I can't find a way to do it especially when you are using equivalent sign.

For example if I have $$ p \land q \Leftrightarrow \lnot q$$ I type `(p AND q) equivalent (NOT q)` and it doesn't work, I have tried other various methods it didn't work either.

Comment: This is very strange, perhaps a bug, since "a equivalent b" is interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `XNOR` instead of `equivalent`.

Comment: yeah it's same and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many people (including mathematicians) often **mistakenly** use $ P \Leftrightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow R $ to indicate *equivalence*, that is $ (P \Leftrightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \Leftrightarrow R) $, which is a way of saying $ P $ is *equivalent* to $ Q $ which is also equivalent to $ R $. (See [goblin's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/440219/367800) to the question *“IFF” (if and only if) vs. “TFAE” (the following are equivalent)*.)

I think it is confusing to think of *if-and-only-if* as equivalence relationship, since being an associative *operator*(1), we are allowed to write expressions such as $ P \Leftrightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow R $, which are not ambiguous at all (compare with $ P \Rightarrow Q \Rightarrow R $, which is only equivalent to $ P \Rightarrow (Q \Rightarrow R) $).

*lhf*'s solution works fine if you are trying to establish an equivalence relationship between **only two** sub-expressions, but XNOR is **not** an equivalent of iff operator! So, for instance, compare the following two expressions: ($ \bar\veebar $ is used for XNOR)

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
P & Q & R & P \Leftrightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow R & P\ \bar\veebar\ Q\ \bar\veebar\ R \\ \hline
\top & \top & \top & \top & \bot \\ \hline
\top & \top & \bot & \bot & \top \\ \hline
\top & \bot & \top & \bot & \top \\ \hline
\top & \bot & \bot & \top & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \top & \top & \bot & \top \\ \hline
\bot & \top & \bot & \top & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \top & \top & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \top \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

As can be seen in the truth table, XNOR and iff operators are not equivalent; furthermore, you might have noticed that they are negation of each other!

I am going to omit the proof, simply because I don't have one, but a given

$$ P_1 \Leftrightarrow P_2 \Leftrightarrow \ldots \Leftrightarrow P_n $$

is equivalent to

$$ P_1\ \bar\veebar\ P_2\ \bar\veebar\ \ldots\ \bar\veebar\ P_n $$

**if and only if** $ n $ is an even number; else is equivalent to

$$ P_1 \veebar P_2 \veebar \ldots \veebar P_n $$

where $ \veebar $ is used for XOR.

Both `XNOR()` and `XOR()` operators are available on WolframAlpha.

---

**(1):** $ P \Leftrightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow R $ is same as $ (P \Leftrightarrow Q) \Leftrightarrow R $ which is also same as $ P \Leftrightarrow (Q \Leftrightarrow R) $.